# How to efficiently edit an item which is deep inside the data set, displayed as react component?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, typescript, algorithm

I have a set, that is *n* levels deep, and on its last level, there is a data row, that contains a value. Displaying that value is easy, but once I edit it, the re-rendering of the whole set takes a lot of time. 
Since to edit it, I have to pass the new value, and item's index back to the highest level.

The code below is just an exemplary, since I'm asking about the possible approach.

High level component:

```
const HighComponent = () => {
   const [data, setData] = useState([]); //array of objects

   render <TableWithData data={data} onChange={setData}/>
}
```

Component that is n-level deep:

```
const FinalComponent = ({item, itemsIndexInPreviousArray, onChangeFromPreviousComponent}) => {
    // this kind of function will assemble the data from the lowest point and return it back
    // to the highest component, that will receive the final data to change, but this kind of 
    // approach will take n*itemsNumber re-renders and time-wise is quiet slow. 
    const changeThisItem = (newValue) => {
         onChangeFromPreviousComponent(newValue, itemsIndexInPreviousArray)
    }
    return (
         <>
             <input value={item} onChange={e => changeThisItem(e.target.value)}/>
         </>
    );
}
```

I would use memoization, but this components are for display only, and they have to trigger an endpoint to update the finalData(top level data) anyway. Whether it is *onChange* event, or bulk trigger.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The need to pass data several levels up (and, probably, consume by several components), indicates the fact that you might need something more sophisticated to manage your state.

You may consider [Redux](https://react-redux.js.org/). It may solve your problem in a nice and effortless manner.

Check out the following live-snippet, paying attention that intermediate component is not getting re-rendered as you type:

```js
const { useEffect } = React,
      { render } = ReactDOM,
      { createStore } = Redux,
      { Provider, useSelector, useDispatch } = ReactRedux

const defaultState = {data:''},
      appReducer = (state=defaultState, action) => {
        switch(action.type){
          case 'SET_DATA': {
            return {...state, data: action.payload}
          }
          default: return state
        }
      },
      store = createStore(appReducer)

const Parent = ({children}) => {
  const data = useSelector(({data}) => data)
  useEffect(() => console.log('Parent is rendered'))
  return (
    <div>
      <div>Current data value is: {data}</div>
      {children}
    </div>
  )
}

const Intermediate = ({children}) => {
  useEffect(() => console.log('Intermediate is rendered'))
  return (
    <div>{children}</div>
  )
}

const Child = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch()
  useEffect(() => console.log('Child is rendered'))
  return (
    <input
        onKeyUp={({target:{value}}) => dispatch({
          type: 'SET_DATA',
          payload: value
        })}
    />
  )
}

render (
  <Provider {...{store}} >
    <Parent>
      <Intermediate>
        <Child />
      </Intermediate>
    </Parent>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.production.min.js"></script><script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script><script crossorigin src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/redux/4.0.4/redux.min.js"></script><script crossorigin src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-redux/7.1.1/react-redux.min.js"></script><div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Oh, so you don't even care about re-renderig the child, since it doesn't have state or value! That's a nice approach, thank you!